# Matrix transformation in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

For example, I have a matrix A (Figure 1).  When the variable `n = 2`, I want it to be transformed to the matrix B. The red rectangle shows the transformation rule of every column. According to this rule, when the `n = 3`, it can become the matrix C.

I have written a script using a for loop method, but it is a waste of time when the matrix A is very large (e.g. 11688* 140000). Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

Figure 1:

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) as follows:

```
result = im2col(A, [n 1], 'sliding');
```

Comment: Yeah, great ! Thank you ! Another method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`implicit expansion`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = reshape(A((1:size(A,1)-n+1) + (0:n-1).', :), n, []);
```

For example assume that `n = 3`. Implicit expansion is used to extract indices of rows:

```
row_ind = (1:size(A,1)-n+1) + (0:n-1).';
```

The following matrix is created:

```
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

Extract the desired rows of `A`:

```
A_expanded = A(row_ind, :)
```

When the matrix `row_ind` is used as an index it behaves like a vector:

```
                1
                2
1   2           3
2   3     ->    2
3   4           3  
                4


A_expanded =

   3   5   7
   6   8   9
   2   6   3
   6   8   9
   2   6   3
   1   2   1
```

Now `A_expanded` can be reshaped to the desired size:

```
result = reshape(A_expanded, n, []);

>>result =

   3   6   5   8   7   9
   6   2   8   6   9   3
   2   1   6   2   3   1
```